# What is the purpose of this capacitor connected to the pad?

Tags: rf, circuit-design

What could be the purpose of capacitor C17 in this 8Mhz series resonant circuit?

[image]

Comment: It might be useful to ensure that a measure instrument plugged into the test point won’t affect significantly the frequency of the resonant circuit. But it’s 0.1µF value is much too high for this. Are you sure the value is correct?

Comment: @user2233709  It could be a placeholder for a capacitor with a TBD value.  Is C17 populated on the actual board?  (I would connect the test point directly, by the way.)

Comment: Odds are it's just AC coupling for a test point.  Filter out any dc component.

Comment: It could also be a test engineering signal injection point too to stimulate the oscillator for calibration or test.